# How to install .bundle packages?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, vmware-workstation

I recently download a package with .bundle extension.

it's VMware-Workstation-Full-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle

I want to install vmware-player but when I open that, it opens with text editor.

i tried

```
chmod a+x VMware-Workstation-Full-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle
```

But result:

> This is a x64 bundle and does not match that of the current architecture. Please download the x86 bundle.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Alt+T` to open the terminal, cd to the directory where the file is and execute

`sudo sh *filename*.bundle`

([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265192/how-do-i-install-vmware-player-from-a-bundle-file))

linux related questions should be asked on Ask Ubuntu